# Perhaps your web.xml contains a typo? omnifaces 1.8.1

Tags: jsf-2, web.xml, omnifaces

I am using Omnifaces 1.8.1 and I got this error while starting Tomcat 7

> WebXml failed to initialize. Perhaps your web.xml contains a typo?
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.parseErrorPageLocations(WebXml.java:434)
>     at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.init(WebXml.java:147)    at
>   org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsInitializerListener.contextInitialized(FacesViewsInitializerListener.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>




    <filter>
            <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<!--     <filter> -->
<!--             <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name> -->
<!--             <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class> -->
<!--     </filter> -->
<!--     <filter-mapping> -->
<!--             <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name> -->
<!--             <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> -->
<!--     </filter-mapping> -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.parseErrorPageLocations(WebXml.java:434)`

`WebXml` is a utility class in omnifaces which provides methods to frequently used `web.xml` elements.

The above line in the stacktrace shows that you have configured an exception class which does not exist in the classspath.

Please post your `<error-page/>` tag snippet in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException means your xml contains a class that cannot be found in the CLASSPATH: either it is a typo - or class is missing because some jar is missing or in wrong place

org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter ?

Comment: I am beginner in Omnifaces and i dont know what's the basic config of omnifaces in web.xml

Comment: OmniFaces requires nothing in `web.xml`. It only fails during startup when your `web.xml` is in invalid format.

Comment: thank you, there is something wrong in my web.xml made that fail